# How to estimate mean and standard deviation of individual result given a sample of batch results?

Tags: inference, mean, standard-deviation

I apologize in advance if my title is not well-worded, or if I am using the wrong tags; this is my first time asking a question here.

I want to analyze how long it takes for a system in production to import data tokens in bulk. Currently, the system generates a log line every time 500 tokens are imported; for a given sample of 30000 tokens, 60 lines are generated (technically 61, since 0 % 500 = 0, but of course I ignore this first figure.)

From this sample of 60 numbers, I can easily calculate the average and standard deviation for each set of 500 tokens, but can I extrapolate this to estimate that for each token import? For instance, please assume that my average is 9878.85 and my SD is 3441.64.

1. Can I divide the average by 500 to estimate the time taken for each import - in this case, 19.76?
2. A quick Google search indicates that I should divide the standard deviation not by 500, but by the root of 500. However, when paired with the answer above, I get 153.92, which does not make sense. Am I doing this the right way?

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider an example in [R](https://www.r-project.org/): the true time per token is $\mu=1{,}000$ and its standard deviation is $\sigma=150$ (in otherwise unspecified units). I'll generate three million in total because simulations are cheap and precision will be higher:

```r
n <- 60
N <- 5E4

mu <- 1000
sigma <- 150

set.seed(1)
sample <- rowSums(matrix(rnorm(N*n, mean=mu, sd=sigma), ncol=n))
#> [1] 60100.43 56909.72 59584.78 59774.39 60773.56 ...
```

We now have a bunch of times it takes to generate 60 tokens. Can we recover the true mean and standard deviation? Your first suggestion is indeed correct:

```r
mean(sample)/n
#> 999.98           ## Pretty much equal to 1,000
```

Now, for the standard deviation (or variance, $\sigma^2$) you have to be careful: rather than just the sum of all observations this uses the *difference* of each observation versus a mean. That means that the more observations you pool, the smaller the average difference is going to be, because you're already "pre-averaging" & increasing precision when pooling if you consider this a single observation. We can see this by applying the above calculation naïvely to the standard deviation:

```r
sd(sample)/n
#> 19.38            ## Not near 150 at all??
```

In fact, what we have just calculated is a [standard error of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error): it is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of $\mu$ (based on the pool size), and isn't solely related to how variable the original measurements were ($\sigma$). Rather, it tells you how precisely you have estimated a mean. As you can see from the formula $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ it also depends on how many measurements you have (pooled): the more, the closer your estimate of the mean will be to the true mean.

We want to know the standard deviation of the *original* measurements however, not their mean estimate, so we can simply reverse the division of the standard error by the square root of the pool size:

```r
sqrt(n)*sd(sample)/n
#> 150.09            ## Close enough to 150
```

This should also help you figure out why you would divide the standard deviation by the square root of the number of observations, and why both are useful in their own way: rather than getting the variance of your original measures (a population characteristic), you then get the variance of a sample statistic of it (how well you've estimated a parameter).

In fact, we can calculate the theoretical value of the standard error of the mean (for pools of 60 samples) and compare that to the value we estimated above:

```r
sigma/sqrt(n)
#> 19.36492         ## Compare to observed value of 19.37738
```

Also note that a standard deviation won't change as you increase sample size (beyond reduced sampling variability & converging to the true value), because as a population characteristic it is constant. With sufficient samples you can make a standard error become essentially zero, including many of its derived statistics such as confidence intervals and *P*-values.

Finally, all of the above assumes that means and standard deviations are sufficiently appropriate summary statistics of your outcome, i.e. that the distribution isn't too skewed or heavy/light-tailed.

Comment: (+1) nice, I hadn't made the connection with the standard error.

Answer (score 2):

The time until something happens usually follows some right-skewed distribution, so just mean and standard deviation might not be the most informative measures to describe the underlying probability distribution. This is also why your standard deviation appears so large compared to the mean: There are apparently many large positive values. A histogram would be a good starting point. Perhaps a [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) might provide a good fit.

With that said, the answers to your questions are:

1. Yes
2. Yes

You can demonstrate that this is correct with a Monte Carlo simulation:

*(For simplicity, I just went with the incorrect assumption of normally distributed values so I can easily specify mean and SD to match yours, just to demonstrate that the calculation is right.)*

```r
set.seed(2024)

MC   <- 10000
Mean <- numeric(MC)
SD   <- numeric(MC)
for(i in 1:MC){
  x       <- rnorm(30000, 9878.85 / 500, 3441.64 / sqrt(500))
  y       <- rep(1:60, l = length(x))
  z       <- tapply(x, y, sum)
  Mean[i] <- mean(z)
  SD[i]   <- sd(z)
}

mean(Mean)
mean(SD)
```

Which gives me a mean of `9878.7` and a standard deviation of `3425.0`. You can get it closer by increasing `MC`.

Answer (score 0):

In a professional lab environment, you'll be better off with the stat math other folks have presented, b/c other folks in a clinical/lab environment think in terms of stats and know what stat terms mean.

But, if you're working with non-math / non-stat professionals (eg: presenting findings to mgmt / execs), it might be better to NOT use average.

My experience with non-math / non-stat folks is when they hear the words "on average", they take that to mean ALL items will be that.. not 1/2 the items will be that or less, and the other 1/2 will be that or higher.

So, it might be better to get avg + 3 std deviations (six sigma style) to estimate that 97% or so of items will get done within that time span.

EG: if you had an avg of 30 seconds per unit w/ std dev of 5 seconds...

A bad way to tell someone would be "on avg, it takes 30 seconds to do each of these". And then later you're called into a meeting when folks are upset b/c "things took longer than you told us!" and you ask why.. and the go "well, I estimated 30 seconds per-unit, and multiplied by 1 million we were going to do.. and actual processing time was MUCH higher!" And then you smh while trying to explain what "average" means and that it can't be used to do estimates of ALL things.

A better way would be... 30 seconds avg + 3 * 5 secs std dev = 30s + 15s = 97% of units are done within 45s. Tell management that, and they'll be much happier with the napkin math they do behind your back with it.

It might also be worthwhile to make an initial pass at your batch runs to determine if there's any outliers. In six sigma, generally anything falling outside (avg + 3 * std devs) is considered "out of control", IE: something outside the system's control impacted it.

It might be good to take a first pass, find all those 4 std dev+ outliers, remove them, and then calc off the remainder of stuff in 3 std devs and below. But, in six sigma and quality control we try to find the 4+ std dev outliers to determine what's impacting system outside system's control. So, it's a good idea to follow-up on why they're outliers. Maybe your system is reaching some kind of "max capacity" in some place, like a bottleneck. EG: in compute processing you get limited by processing, memory and input/output. Maybe you have lots of cpu & ram, but i/o is getting bottlenecked some place creating delays and outliers. In theory your process should run on avg 30 s, but you end up with some outliers taking 200 s. Maybe it's when system gets flooded with processing, and that's when bottlenecks start to impact. So, could look into load-leveling the system or find a way to add more resources.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While I like the idea of not just reporting an average, I still downvoted this and would like to explain why: (1) In a normal distribution, mean + 3 * SD does not cover 97% of the distribution, but closer to 99.9%. (2) Regardless of the correct number, it is still misleading, because the actual distribution is very likely skewed. (3) Blanket removal of observations beyond 4 SD is also not a good idea, as these observations may actually be far more common than you think in a right-skewed distribution.